# Changing a button's font color when touched in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5

I'm brand new to iOS with only Action Script 3.0 as a programming background.  Objective C is looking unbelievably foreign to me thus far.  I'm working with the latest version of Xcode and am trying to learn by taking baby steps, and too many tutorials start at far too high a level for a new guy like me.

I'm trying to have a label or button change font color when it is touched, and return to its original color when it is touched again.  I know it's probably stupidly simple, but I need to start somewhere.  Thanks much.

Comment: There's plenty of good books like this one.  S.O. is more for answering specific issues - not so much teach me about x,y and z :)  http://www.amazon.com/Programming-iOS-Fundamentals-iPhone-Development/dp/1449319343/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1348107884&sr=8-5&keywords=iphone+development

Comment: I thought I was being very specific with the above question.  If Stackoverflow is not for a beginner's specific questions, then I'll try to find another forum.

Comment: It's great for beginners.  SO isn't as much as a "do it for me site" - rather, I tried this out (with code), and here's what I experienced or the error I got, what do I do.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy to change a `UIButton` color property when it is touched.

```
-(IBAction)changeColor:(id)sender
{
UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender; 

if(btn.enabled)
{
    btn.enabled=NO;
    btn.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];    


}
else
{
    btn.enabled=YES;
    btn.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];  
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @interface ViewController ()
{
BOOL muteIsSelected;
}
```

@end

```
- (IBAction)yourButton:(id)sender {
if(muteIsSelected == false)
{
   yourButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    muteIsSelected = true;
}
else if (muteIsSelected == true)
{
     yourButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    muteIsSelected = false;
}
}
```